# Why Config Example Service file does not have @Injectable decorator?

Tags: service, nestjs

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration
I was trying to follow the example mentioned in the Configuration section of NestJS, but I noticed that there is a Service class (ConfigService) defined without an @Injectable decorator. Was it just a mistake or it can be defined in this way too?

As per the doc I read on nestjs Service which are also Providers needs to have Injectable decorator defined https://docs.nestjs.com/providers

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a mistake. All providers need to have the `@Injectable()` decorator. I would also suggest making the `ConfigModule` global by using the `@Global()` decorator as described in the docs.